# Hadamard's formula and the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been tasked with determining lim sup $|a_{n}|^{1/n}$ for the polynomial defined in relation to the Fibonacci sequence:

$\sum^{\infty}_{0}a_{n}z^{n},$
$z\in\mathbb{C}$,

where $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for $n>0.$

Is it sufficient to argue that since the fibonacci sequence is non-convergent, the radius of convergence is 0, and therefore the answer is infinity?

otherwise, how can I show this explicitly?

I have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (a_{n-2} + a_{n-1})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

(modulus removed for positive real values).

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, the terms within parentheses approach $\infty$ without bound. But I'm not sure what to do with the n root...

---

OK, so I substituted the closed form of the sequence in above then I tried to find the limit of the logarithm of the quantity to help simplify. So I end up with

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{1}{n}log(\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n} - (1-\sqrt{5})^{n})}{2^{n}\sqrt{5}}) $

Then

$\frac{1}{n}log(\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n} - (1-\sqrt{5})^{n})}{2^{n}\sqrt{5}}) = \frac{1}{n}(log(numerator) - log(denominator))$

This simplifies further to...

$\frac{1}{n}[\log{ ((1 + \sqrt(5))^{n} - (1 - \sqrt(5))^{n}} - n\log{2}-\log{\sqrt{5}}$]

...
At this point, can I just argue that the first logarithmic term approaches infinity since 1/n diverges more slowly than the numerator, and the latter terms are just the subtraction of a negative constant?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will correct.

Comment: Do you know the closed form of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Note the $F_n$ is the integer closest to $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$, where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$, the golden ratio.

Comment: "[S]ince the fibonacci sequence is non-convergent, the radius of convergence is $0$" is an incorrect deduction. The sequence $a_n=2^n$ is non-convergence, but the radius of convergence of $\sum_n a_n z^n = \sum_n 2^n z^n$ equals $\frac12$.

Comment: Greg, thanks for pointing out my flawed reasoning. Also, the closed form clue was really helpful. Thank you. I initially saw "golden ratio" and immediately thought "I don't know how to make that mysterious thing useful here" ...

Comment: I believe that the second term in the closed form expression for $a_{n}$ (Binet Formula) has absolute value less than one, so approaches zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so only the first term involving $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ remains.   Then raising to $1/n$ cancels the exponent.  I believe this was implied by one of the earlier comments.   I don't know if taking the log is necessary here. I hope this helps.